# Can a zmq socket read and write in two threads at the same time?

Tags: c++, zeromq

ZMQ doc says that a ZMQ socket can be used in multiple threads if you hit a full memory barrier between threads. This does not sound good for having one thread sitting blocked in `zmq_recv` while another thread calls `zmq_send`. Is this allowed for, or do I need to set a proxy/broker after all?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the full memory barrier will allow a single socket to be *passed* between multiple threads, not *used concurrently* in multiple threads.

Comment: Indeed for the "passed". Adding to that, if the OP doesn't want thread blocking, he can use the poller and do operations when the sockets are ready.